# C program : function not being called from main

Tags: c, windows, function, embedded

I am programming the Renesas RX63N microcontroller, in C using Renesas High-performance Embedded Workshop. The problem that I face is that a function, connectWiFi(), is not being executed from main. Following is the function's prototype:

```
typedef char String[5000];
void connectWiFi(String id, int auth, String psk);
```

The function body is this:

```
void connectWiFi(String id, int  auth, String psk)
{
    printf("log 0.1\n");
    char cwTemp2[10];
    String one,two,three;
    ...

}
```

And I am calling the function from main as follows

```
void main(void)
{
    initPhant("data.sparkfun.com", "Public_Key", "Private_Key");
    xB_begin(XBEE_BAUD);//uart initialization
    // Set up WiFi network
    printf("Testing network\n");
    // connectWiFi will attempt to connect to the given SSID, 
//using encryption mode "encrypt", and the passphrase string given.
    printf("log0\n");
    connectWiFi("abcd", 2, "qwerty");
    // Once connected, print out our IP address
    printf("Connected!\n");
....
}
```

As you see, I am using the printf() calls to log the progress of the execution. But the debugger console prints only these:

```
Testing network
log0
```

The next printf() statement is not being printed. Thus I believe that the execution never reaches the function.
Another weird thing here is that the code actually stops running after printing "log0"- when I look at the program counter in the dissambler(a part of the debugger) at this point, the instruction it is stuck at, is labelled "???".

Thanks in advance for your help, I've been cracking my head for several hours on this problem.

Comment: If this is C, why tag C++? (the languages and their "natural" solutions may be very different)

Comment: It seems that String[5000] is quite large. Could it be possible that connectWiFi contains a String local variable and causes a stack overflow?

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks for your input, I've removed the C++ tag.

Comment: @juhist But the printf() statement is the first in the function connectWiFi, so should it not be printed before anything else happens?

Comment: Use Hew debugger to step into the code if you have an ICE (in circuit emulator). Your code looks OK. You can test by removing all code from function except the `print` and can gradually add more code.

Comment: Is the `typedef char String[5000];` your invention or does it come from the toolkit?

Comment: @Susch, well, there is at least one variable after printf so there could be more variables one of which could be a String (because there was a ... line). It may be possible that the printf call causes a stack overflow, if the compiler decides to push the local variables to stack immediately at the start of the function even if the variables are declared later.

Comment: @chqrlie It is our invention, we needed to import a C++ code into C, and so we used the existing String datatype and made changes to the rest of the problem based on that.
Would that create a problem?

Comment: @Sush: yes it may pose a problem: try and make this typedef a much smaller one such as `typedef char String[100];` and see if it still hangs at the same location.

Comment: @juhist Thank you very much! This was the cause of the problem. The function connectWiFi declared three String variables, which had caused the stack to overflow.

Comment: As @chqrlie had suggested, once I reduced the size of the stack, I got all the printf outputs. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Be sure to accept my answer, then. And consider editing your question to show that the `connectWiFi` function indeed has `String` variables, because now the question doesn't show enough to show the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the following:

```
void connectWiFi(String id, int  auth, String psk)
{
    printf("log 0.1\n");
    char cwTemp2[10];
    ...

}
```

You didn't specify what ... contains but you had previously defined

```
typedef char String[5000];
```

So, because the line before the `connectWiFi` call is executed but the first line of the `connectWiFi` function is not executed, it looks like `...` contains `String` declarations which cause the stack to overflow.

This is especially likely on microcontroller systems that have a limited stack space.

The solution is to not allocate such large strings from the stack. Allocating such large strings from the heap should be avoided too as microcontrollers have limited memory. Better to allocate exactly how many bytes you need.